# Geopoint at parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform, geopoints

Im trying to add a marker retrieving the data i have saved from a user, i have saved a Geoping but i dont know how to put the values separated,because i get the latitud and longitud together from the database and i need the vaules separated so i can do the following:

```
double lat =  <geopoint parse.com>;
double lon = <geopoint parse.com>;
LatLng ubicacion = new LatLng(lat, lon);
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ubicacion).title("Marker in Sydney"));
```

Could someone helpme with these?

Comment: `parseObject.getParseGeoPoint("location")`

Comment: thanks a lot mate ill try that in a few hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try on this way.

It's getting using a parse query

```
loc.getLatitude();
loc.getLongitude();

@SuppressWarnings("null")
public static void showMap(double lati, double longi, GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lati, longi)));
    drawMarkerWithCircle(1000, new LatLng(lati, longi), googleMap);
}

public static void drawMarkerWithCircle(double rad, LatLng position, GoogleMap googleMap) {
    double radiusInMeters = rad;
    int strokeColor = 0x0000ff;
    int shadeColor = 0x44ff0000;
    CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions().center(position).radius(radiusInMeters).fillColor(shadeColor)
            .strokeColor(strokeColor).strokeWidth(8);
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, 10));
}
```

Comment: I think this might be the opposite of what the question is asking (writing instead of reading)?